# Find the lcm of $23,24,30,32,40,41,43,50$ where these numbers are in base $6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Well it's easy to find the lcm if i convert these numbers into base $10$ and then solve.

This question is from the book Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight and in the question they have specifically asked to find the lcm without converting into base $10$.

I don't know how to do it.

It would help if anyone shows me how to find out lcm of 2 numbers in base 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication table, base $6$ for $2,3,5$.

\begin{array}{r|rrrrr}
     & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
   2 &  2 &  4 & 10 & 12 & 14\\
   3 &  3 & 10 & 13 & 20 & 23\\
   5 &  5 & 14 & 23 & 32 & 41\\
\end{array}

Divisibility rules in base $6$:

\begin{align}
   2 & : \text{Ends in $0,2,4$.}\\
   3 & : \text{Ends in $0, 3$.}\\
   5 & : \text{Digit sum is a multiple of $5$.}
\end{align}

Hence

$\qquad 2 \; \text{divides} \; 24,30,32,40,50$

$\qquad 3 \; \text{divides} \; 23,30,40,43,50$

$\qquad 5 \; \text{divides} \; 23,32,41,50$

Using the above information, we find

$23 = 3 \cdot 5$

$24 = 2 \cdot 12 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 = 2^4$

$30 = 3 \cdot 10 = 3 \cdot2 \cdot 3 = 2 \cdot 3^2$

$32 = 5 \cdot 4 = 2^2 \cdot 5$

$40 = 3 \cdot 12 = 2^3 \cdot 3$

$41 = 5^2$

$43 = 3 \cdot 13 = 3^3$

$50 = 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$

Putting this into a table, we get

\begin{array}{rrrrr}
23 &= 2^0 & 3^1 & 5^1 \\
24 &= 2^4 & 3^0 & 5^0 \\
30 &= 2^1 & 3^2 & 5^0 \\
32 &= 2^2 & 3^0 & 5^1 \\
40 &= 2^3 & 3^1 & 5^0 \\
41 &= 2^0 & 3^0 & 5^2 \\
43 &= 2^0 & 3^3 & 5^0 \\
50 &= 2^1 & 3^1 & 5^1 \\
\end{array}

So the lowest common multiple is
$2^4 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2
 = (2 \cdot 3)^3 \cdot 2 \cdot 41
 = 1000 \cdot 122
 = 122000$

Answer (score 1):

Collect prime factors of each of the terms in base 6.

$23 = 3*5, 24 = 2*2*2*2, 30 = 2*3*3, 40 = 2*2*2*3, 41 = 5*5, 43 = 3*3*2*2$, etcetera...

Then find the lcm...

Comment: $43_6 = 3^3$; $2^23^2=100_6$

Comment: Oops.. I should double check my answers..

Comment: How exactly did you do all this **without converting into base $10$**?

Comment: I don't see what's so surprising about it.  Base $6$ has obvious divisibility rules for $2$ and $3$.  The only hard one to do is $41$ and even that falls pretty quickly: considering how small it is you need only try $5$ and that works.

Comment: Trial and error on small factors. Up to 5 that should not be too difficult if you do it correctly. 41 was the most difficult one, but if you add 5 you'd get 50, so 41 is (10-5).

Comment: @DanUznanski: And also by $5$, since a number on base $b$ is divisible by $b-1$ if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by $b-1$. But you still have to (possibly) deal with other factors.

Comment: Well, my method would not work for $lcm(ABFFED801, 78FE2)$ in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

In the scale of six,  $$23=3\times 5$$ $$24=4\times 4$$ $$30=3\times 3\times 2$$ $$32=4\times 5$$ $$40=2\times 3\times 4$$ $$41=5\times 5$$ $$43=3\times 3\times 3$$ $$50=3\times 5\times 2$$.

> $$ LCM= 3^{3}\times 5^{2}\times 4^{2} = 122000$$

Comment: How exactly did you guess all this **without converting into base $10$**?

Comment: By using @Pieter21's method. But I don't know how it struck him.

Comment: Well then, first - you should by the least credit @Pieter21's for that (and by the most, if the answer doesn't contribute anything further, then avoid from posting it altogether). Second - it is not quite clear (at least to me) how he or she did that either.

Comment: Well, I was not complete (intentionally to leave some exercise) and not correct, so two good reasons to post this.

Comment: For the method: I saw 40 and 41, and thought, hey, they will be relatively prime. And I saw 30 and 32, they will obviously also in base 6 have a common factor of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $lcm(a,b,c)=lcm(lcm(a,b),c)$ and $lcm(a,b)=\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$, so what you should do the to understand the multiplication and division (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division )in base 6, as well as the division algorithm for computing the $\gcd(a,b)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm ).

Take a=24,b=30 for example, 
$$30=24\times 1+2,$$
$$24=12\times 2+0.$$
So $\gcd(24,30)=2$, and moreover $lcm(24,30)=\frac{24\times 30}{\gcd(24,30)}=\frac{24\times 30}{2}=12\times 30=400$.

PS:All the numbers above are in base 6. And the the number below are in base 16.

Take  a=ABFFED801,b=78FE2 for example,
$$ABFFED801=78FE2\times 16BEC+BDA9，$$
$$78FE2=BDA9\times A+2748，$$
$$BDA9=2748\times 4+2089，$$
$$2748=2089\times 1+6BF，$$
$$2089=6BF\times 4+58D，$$
$$6BF=58D\times 1+132，$$
$$58D=132\times 4+C5，$$
$$132=C5\times 1+6D，$$
$$C5=6D\times 1+58，$$
$$6D=58\times 1+15，$$
$$58=15\times 4+4，$$
$$15=4\times 5+1，$$
$$4=4\times 1+0.$$
So $\gcd(ABFFED801,78FE2)=4$, and moreover $lcm(ABFFED801,78FE2)=\frac{ABFFED801\times 78FE2}{\gcd(ABFFED801,78FE2)}=\frac{ABFFED801\times 78FE2}{4}=ABFFED801\times 1E3F8=1452A7D06B23F8$.

In a word, you should try to do multiplication in original base. Since we are used to do that in base 10, it's possible to make mistake in that way. So you need a multiplication  table with carries. Also take base 6 for example, you have the multiplication  table with carries:
$$\matrix{(ab,carries) & 0 & 1 & 2 &3 & 4 & 5 \cr
             0 & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,0)  \cr
             1 & (0,0) & (1,0) & (2,0) & (3,0) & (4,0) & (5,0)  \cr
             2 & (0,0) & (2,0) & (4,0) & (0,1) & (2,1) & (4,1)  \cr
             3 & (0,0) & (3,0) & (0,1) & (3,1) & (0,2) & (3,2)  \cr
             4 & (0,0) & (4,0) & (2,1) & (0,2) & (4,2) & (2,3)  \cr
             5 & (0,0) & (5,0) & (4,1) & (3,2) & (2,3) & (1,4)  \cr}$$
It's easy to show that the carries are less than 5 as if they are less then 9 in base 10. Again, such multiplication is quite different from the usual multiplication in base 10.

Finally, I suggest that you convert the number into base 10 and compute the number as usual unless you would like to do mathematical proves in base 6.